# Changing the default size of iTerm2 when it opens

Tags: macos, iterm

I feel like this is a pretty stupid question but I Googled it and played around with it and still didn't figure it out so here we go:

When I open iTerm2, it opens in a default size. How can I set it to open in a different window size?

Answer (score 90):

The easiest way to have iTerm2 open with a specific size, position and number of windows is:

- Get it all set up the way you'd like to see it when it opens. Have all your iTerm2 windows sized and place where you like them.
- From the top menu select `Window -> Save Window Arrangement` and give it a name
- Go to the Preferences and under the Arrangements section find the named arrangement, select it and press the `Set Default` button

[image: Set default arrangement]

- Go to the General page and select `Open default window arrangement`

[image: Make iTerm open it on startup]

Now, when you start iTerm2, it'll use your saved arrangement to place, size and create the number of windows you saved. You can adjust the settings any time by placing things as you like them and re-saving the default arrangement.

Comment: Thanks, I found step number 2 but couldn't find step number 3, do you have a screen shot that can help?

Comment: I'll add a screen shot tonight.

Comment: This is a great answer. It was driving me crazy having to resize and position  on a daily basis.

Comment: Perfect solution. Sadly, the settings UX isn't as straightforward and probably too advanced for me to understand.

Comment: Its working only when it is opened for the first time. On creating a new window, it still looks minimized. Is there any solution for that ?

Answer (score 41):

[image]

​​​​​​

Comment: Careful about the numbers that you enter for the new window dimensions...  I figured that a max value would mean it would take up the room that it could on the designated starting screen, but it didn't.  Now iTerm crashes every time I launch it because I can't find the preferences file to change the value back!

Comment: In OSX you find this under Profiles => Open profiles, then select default profile and click edit "profiles"